# Gigolo translated as 基哥儿龙（音）?

Tags: word, transliteration

There was some HK movie that translated (read: transliterated) `gigolo` as something like `基哥儿龙`（音）.

I cannot find anything online with different combinations of characters for `ji-ger-long`.

Any ideas what the phrase was?

Comment: Hmmm do you mean this one? [鴨王 (The Gigolo)](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/鴨王).

Comment: @Stan I believe it's in 八星报喜 actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a Hong Kong movie, it is likely in Cantonese

> [基](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/941/) is transliteration of 'gay'
>
> /gei1/
>
> *[5] (Cantonese slang only) phonetic translation of "gay" i.e. male homosexual e.g. 搞基,*

~

> [哥](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/626/)
>
> /go1/
>
> It is common to address a man with a  suffix  "哥", e.g. 晶哥 [zing1 go1*4], 叻哥 [lek1 go1*4].*
>
> remember [犀利哥](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%A8%8B%E5%9B%BD%E8%8D%A3/9510680?fromtitle=%E7%8A%80%E5%88%A9%E5%93%A5&fromid=34025)?

~

> [牛郎](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/50340/)
>
> /ngau4 long4 /
>
> a gigolo, a male sex worker

牛郎 is a male sex worker (serving older female mostly)

基哥牛郎 most likely refers to 'male sex worker (specialized in serving male clients)'